# APEXCHARTS How to prevent last dataLabel in Line Chart ('datetime') to get cut off?

Tags: apexcharts

I'm building an Apex Line Chart with the `x-axis` set to `type: 'datetime'`. Unfortunately the last dataLabel always gets cut off ->

[image]

Is there a setting that I'm missing to prevent this?

```
const options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            width: '100%',
            height: 300,
            toolbar: {
                show: false
            },
            parentHeightOffset: 0,
        },
        colors: ['#a9d4a5'],
        xaxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 800,
                },      
            },
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontSize: 14,
                //              colors: ['white']
            },
            background: {
                //              enabled: false,
                padding: 10,
                borderWidth: 3,
                borderColor: '#a9d4a5',
                //              foreColor: 'var(--color-main)',
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            x: {
                show: false
            },
            y: {
                title: {
                    formatter: (seriesName) => '',
                },
            }
        },
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this at the moment by:

1. making the overflow of the chart svg visible
2. adding some extra padding to the chart-container

```
.apexcharts-svg {
    overflow: visible;
}

.chart-container {
    padding: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2.7rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that worked for me:

```
grid: {
    padding: { 
        left: 40, 
        right: 50 
    }
}
```

Modify the padding values as per your requirements.